# capturar e usar um objeto no aplicativo a partir de uma dll (todos em delphi)

Tags: delphi

Tenho um exe em delphi e uso uma dll também em delphi. No exe tenho um tdatabase para conexão com um banco, e na dll gostaria de capturar e usar este componente sem necessidade de criar um novo tdatabase para acessar o banco, evitando duas conexões simultâneas com o banco.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não seria só passar um SQLConnection por parâmetro ?

Comment: Se passasse o SqlConnection por parâmetro ele criaria uma nova conexão e é isso que eu mão quero